# Accessing a text box inside table row using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using the following code

```
<tr id="row">
<td><input type="text" name ="first" id="first" onclick="goto("row")"/>
</td>
<td><input type="text" name ="second" id="second"/>
</td>
</tr>

<script>
function goto(row)
{
var row=document.getElementById("row");

}
</script>
```

here in the goto() function i am getting the table row by using id.I need to get the second  text box inside this row when i clicking the first text box.How can i get the second text box using the  table row id. Any idea ?.

Comment: Why not just say `.getElementById("second");` ?

Comment: i cant use .getElementById("second"); because am generating these table rows dynamically. so each row will have the same items and ids.But am changing the id of dynamically generated row so that i can access each items in the particular row

Comment: If you generate them dynamically I would suggest assigning each one a unique consistent id (like ID1, ID2, ID2) and then you can say if you click on the ID1, select ID2 (you would do an increment in your script).

Answer (score 0):

First off, you're missing some equals (=) signs in your HTML.  You might want to change that to name="first" and name="second".  Secondly, I'm not sure why you have two elements with the same id of "second" when you could have changed one of them to "first" so they don't collide, and then you could easily select the second one with getElementById("second").  Simple mistake, right?

Answer (score 0):

Change the ids, make them unique and you could directly access the input textbox like:

```
var txtbox = document.getElementById("YourTextboxId");
```